# Number Line [GRE]

Tags: gre-exam

Between a number $5$ and $10$ on a number line,exclusive , a dark gray tick mark is placed at every multiple of $\frac{1}{3}$ and a light gray tick mark is placed at every multiple of $\frac{1}{9}$. At how many places will a dark gray tick mark and light gray tick mark overlap?

I can't see the systematic way of solving this. Can anyone provide a systematic way of approaching such a problem? The book I have its solution is not handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every multiple of $\frac{1}{3}$ is also a multiple of $\frac{1}{9}$. Thus, there will be overlap at every multiple of $\frac{1}{3}$, of which there are $((10 - 5) * 3) - 1$ (Three greater than each of $5,6,7,8,9$, less the one mark at $10$.)

This gives a total of $14$.

Comment: Why multiplying by 3?

Comment: @user1772052, that's because he is dividing by $1/3$.

Answer (score 0):

You gonna have to solve this equation, because  the number of ways the two ticks will overlap is $\frac{n}{3} = \frac{y}{9}$, but we can write $y=3n$

$$5 \leq \frac{n}{3} \leq 10$$
$$15 \leq n \leq 30$$

This means that there are 16 possible answers for n and the two ticks will overlap 16 times.

Comment: The problem specifies that between 5 and 10 is exclusive.

Comment: Then the answer would be 14 ;D

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the numbers by $9$, then you have the range $45,\cdots,90$ exclusive, with the '$\frac{1}{9}$th' marks at every integer, and '$\frac{1}{3}$rd' marks at every multiple of $3$. Hence this reduces to finding all the multiples of $3$ in the (inclusive) range $48,\cdots,87$, which is quickly computed to be $\frac{87-48}{3}+1= 14$.

Answer (score 0):

Concept : Overlap at LCM($\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}$,$\displaystyle\frac{1}{9}$) = $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}$

Just take one interval 5 to 6

$5$ + $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}$  , $5$ + $\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}$ , $5$ + $\displaystyle\frac{3}{3}=6$

so from $5$ to $6$ there are $3$ points ,

similary 3 points between $6$ to $7$ , $7$ to $8$ ,$8$ to $9$ , $9$ to $10$  (but 10 not included )

so $(5 \times 3 ) - 1$ =

$14$

[image]